# how can i get properties as well as its method of a class on node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new on Node.js. Here I created a user model with some method like `save`, `addToCart`, `findById` and so on.

Here is my User Model

```
const getDb = require('../util/database').getDb;
const mongoDb = require('mongodb');

const objectId = mongoDb.ObjectID;

module.exports = class User {
    constructor (username, email, cart, id){
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.cart = cart; // {items : []}
        this._id = id;
    }


    save(){
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('users').insertOne(this)
        .then(result => {
            console.log("User Created Succesfully");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    addToCart(product){
        const updateCart = { items : [{productId: new objectId(product._id), quantity : 1}]};
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('users')
        .updateOne({_id: new objectId(this._id)}, {$set: {cart: updateCart } })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    }

    static findById(userId){
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection('users').find({_id: new objectId(userId)}).next();
    }
}
```

at the beginning i am creating a req.user by following method:

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    User.findById('5de9f4f7f099c426505c0c9e')
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        req.user = new User(user.username,user.email, user.cart, user._id);
        next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Still, there is all ok I got `req.user` but when I am trying to call a method of user model from another script I couldn't access the method `addToCart` of User model.

Here is the code where I am calling the user method

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
    const prodId = req.body.productId;
    Product.findById(prodId, product => {
        console.log(req.user);
        return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Shop",result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    //res.redirect('/cart');
}
```

There is no error at console. But, cart properties is not getting updated. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Firstly, you are not saving the req.user, second thing is: try not to do this because mongoose documents are heavy. They’ll make your request object unnecessarily bulky.

Comment: sorry i can't understand because i am new at node.js

Comment: You should create resources only in request controllers not in middlewares.